# django override admin template

Tags: django

I am following [part 2 of the Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial02/). I am trying to override an admin template (`base_site.html`)

I copied the file from the `django/contrib/admin/templates` to `mytemplates/admin/base_site.html`

I also updated settings.py:

```
#Base Directory
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

#Template directories
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mytemplates'),)
```

I tried putting the mytemplates folder in the root of the project folder as well as in the mysite folder with no luck. Any pointers would be great!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

EDITED PREVIOUS USER RESPONSE -- THIS WORKS:

I think your relative path to the templates directory is wrong.

If you follow these steps it should work: (I tested it myself)

1. Put the `mytemplates` dir side by side with the `manage.py` file

   ```
   project
   -app1
   -app2
   -mytemplates
       -admin
           -base_site.html
   -manage.py
   ```
2. Change the TEMPLATE_DIRS to:

   ```
   TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mytemplates'),)
   ```
3. Make sure the order of the template loader is:

   ```
   TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (

       'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
       'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',

   )
   ```

Comment: Shouldn't `admin` be a subdirectory to `mytemplates/` with this configuration?

Comment: this works, as long as you use the correct folder name in `TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join ...`

Comment: it's confusing because I've seen people specify templates within the app, within the project, and now here -- at the project-base? I don't even know what to call this level

Answer (score 1):

@YardenST's answer *almost* worked for me. I guess it's a matter of configuration.

In case you run into trouble, I suggest you use this line:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mytemplates'),)
```

Next, put a breakpoint to show the actual outcome, or alternatively use `print TEMPLATE_DIRS`.

**That's where you should place the templates you want to override.**

Answer (score 1):

@kat-russo, thx ;)

I tried to setup admin templates according to docs

```
project_name
-app1
-app2
-project_name //main folder -> settings.py , urls.py, wsgi.py
-templates
-admin
  -project_name
     base.html
```

without success, but

```
 -templates
   -admin
      base.html
```

works for me.

my config (Django 1.10.4 w/Django CMS 3.4.1)

```
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates"),],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'sekizai.context_processors.sekizai',
            'cms.context_processors.cms_settings',
        ],

    },
},
]
```

Comment: Thanks @3176243. I was breaking my head trying to figure out how to do this setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can override all templates.

Create an admin directory in templates and add the files.

The all files.

https://github.com/django/django/tree/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin