# django customize admin html tables

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

i was wondering how can i customize my django default admin page, and add a new "html" table in order to have for instance two tables in my default admin page side by side, but with different information.
i have tried reading the django documentation but i can't seem to find a solution for my problem.

i was looking into https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/intro/tutorial02/ but with no luck.

can anyone help??

Comment: possible duplicate of [django override admin template](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754545/django-override-admin-template)

Comment: You want two list view pages on the same page?

Comment: the comment above solved my problem