# Django 1.6 admin panel customization

Tags: python, django, django-admin, customization

Now I'm developing a feedback application,

So, the admin must see messages from users, filter them(read/unread) and mark them as important.
I have already done all the functionality I need, but i cannot customize my headers.
For example.
There is a default header in change list(see the screenshot, this header is selected),
How can I delete these headers or customize them?[image: Screenshot]

Great thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, the answer from @mayankTUM is *not* correct. It does not follow the [django design philosophies](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/misc/design-philosophies/) and should not be implemented (@mayankTUM himself mentions one of the problems of his solution however there are many, many more)!

Basically, what you need to do can be done by [overriding the admin templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/admin/#overriding-admin-templates). Because there are some problems with that (I will explain later), here's exactly what 
I did to solve your requirement:

1. Created a directory named `admin` in my `templates` folder.
2. Copied there the `change_list.html` template from `<django>\contrib\admin\templates\admin\change_list.html`.
3. Added the following to the end of the new `change_list.html`: `{% block content_title %}Hello world!{% endblock %}`

Now, instead of "Select ... to change" it will print "Hello world!"

I have to notice that copying the *whole* `change_list.html` is not DRY - it'd be much better if I just created the file, made it extend from `admin/change_list.html` and add the `content_title`. However this is not working and will lead to infinite recursion (please check this bug report https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15053 ) -- this is the problem to which I was referring before. A better solution that copying over the whole template is discussed in the following questions:

[Django: Overriding AND extending an app template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3967801/django-overriding-and-extending-an-app-template)
and 
[How to override and extend basic Django admin templates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6583877/how-to-override-and-extend-basic-django-admin-templates) and 
[django override admin template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754545/django-override-admin-template)

PS: My `TEMPLATE_DIRS` and `TEMPLATE_LOADERS` project settings are these:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    PROJECT_PATH.child('templates'),
)

TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```