# Django: Overrideing base_site.html

Tags: django, django-admin

Folks,
I tried following steps in the [Django Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/intro/tutorial02/) for customizing the admin template. I followed the steps to the letter, creating a directory structure as follows:

```
 - myproject/
   - myproject/
     - templates/
       - admin/
         - base_site.html
   - myapp1/
   - manage.py
```

I edited base_site.html to change text "Django site admin" to "My site admin".

I edited myproject/settings.py to add:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')]
```

Upon running this, my changes to base_site.html did not take effect.

I then followed the advise on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754545/django-override-admin-template) and created the following directory structure:

```
 - myproject/
   - myproject/
   - templates/
     - admin/
       - base_site.html
   - myapp1/
   - manage.py
```

And added the following to my settings.py file:

```
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'..', 'mytemplates'),)
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
)
```

I am still greeted by "Django administration" when I visit the admin page. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

BASE_DIR refers to, well, the base dir, So you should use the original value of TEMPLATE_DIRS with the new layout.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for your help. While Python and Django have been super intuitive overall, the template directories stuff seems like black magic. Clearly I am not thinking about this the right way. Can you point me at a good tutorial or documentation that will set me right?