# Changing Admin Templates - Django tutorial 2

Tags: django, templates

This question was answered more or less [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754545/django-override-admin-template) but it didn't work to me and as far I can see more people have the same problem.

In my settings.py I have this lines:

```
 #TEMPLATE_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'..', 'templates'),]
 TEMPLATE_DIRS = ("/root/GODJANGO/thedjango/django_project",)
```

The comented line didn't work. It works if I write the full path but It's not professional and I don't wanna have problems when I three months later I migrate my server because I will not remember this thing.

1. Can anybody tell me how to write My Path correctly ("dynamically, I mean")
2. Please tell me where is the best directory to put my templates folder and also my admin templates folder

Comment: What does it show: "print [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'..', 'templates'),]"?

Comment: I tried several times: print [os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'..', 'templates'),]
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: Why have you changed TEMPLATE_DIRS at all? The default value is BASE_DIR/templates, which should work fine for the tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the following project layout:

```
manage.py
myproject/
          settings.py
          urls.py
          wsgi.py
          templates/
                   admin/
app1/
app2/
```

Then you can dynamically set your template directory by putting the following in your `settings.py`:

```
...
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(SETTINGS_PATH, "templates")
)
...
```

if your template folder is in the parent folder to the `settings.py` you will need something like:

```
...
SETTINGS_PATH = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
PROJECT_FOLDER = (os.path.split(SETTINGS_PATH))[0]  # get the parent directory
TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_FOLDER, "templates")
)
...
```

As you can see, we are manually traversing the file tree to find where the templates folder is and assigning it dynamically.

The best place for your templates folder depends on your project layout (< 1.4 or >= 1.4) but it would be probably safest to say that it should be alongside your `settings.py` file. Your admin template folder will go *inside* your base templates folder: `templates/admin/`.

Comment: That work ! Thanks! I would like to vote your answer up but I have no enough reputation to do that, so if you vote my question up I will give you gratefully the up vote. "Gracies" (;

Comment: If it worked you can accept it as the correct answer by clicking the tick beside the upvote buttons.

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to do with this paramater ".." in the commented line?

if it is means parent directory you can use `os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)`

Second part:

It depends you or team work with; i love to keep templates directory in every app's directory (and if you do like this you don't need to define `TEMPLATE_DIRS`). I mean if i have templates of news app, they goes `../news/templates/`. But this time my friend (front-end developer) says i cant find them, can we put all of them in one place?
so i put them in one directory with sub directories (`../templates/news/`). This main templates directory is in main project directory (near the manage.py file). And if you add this main directory to `INSTALLED_APPS` (because its kind an app) you don't need to define `TEMPLATE_DIRS` too. And even you can create models.py admin.py files here.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the truth is that I'm a very recent user in Django so I'm only following the official tutorials by the moment and I want to do the right thing and be sure about what way I take. Regards!

Answer (score 0):

Considering the second part of your question and according to [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bRnm8f6Wavk) the safest part for your templates is to create a `templates` dir under your projects main directory (e.g. `blog`).

As for the first part i am not sure.

Comment: I will appreciate if you tell me in what minute it is said, thanks!

Comment: @BugFixer i just  saw the comment sorry for the delay, however as i am not really experienced too i recommend to watch the whole tutorial. Project structure can be a pain sometimes.