# How to override Django admin page?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-admin

I overrides admin templates and I have something like this:

```
{% for app in app_list %}
    <li>
        <a href="#">
            <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/list.png"/>
            <span>{{ app.name }}</span>
        </a>
        <ul class="drawer" style="display: none;">
            {% for model in app.models %}
                <li>
                    <a href="{{ model.admin_url }}">
                        <span>{{ model.name }}</span>
                    </a>
                </li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
```

But it shows me menu only on index page. How to get app_list on each admin page?

Comment: What do you mean in each admin page ? can you give more details on what you want and what you have ?

Comment: for example in edit/add new object page or in change_list page, I want to show menu generated from app_list - always

Comment: I think your only solution is to modify `base_site.html` since every page extends from it `{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}` and include what you want !

Answer (score 0):

I think your only solution is to modify `base_site.html` since every page extends from it `{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}` and include what you want ! You have to create an admin folder and place your modified `base_site.html` inside. You have to make sure that django loads the template dir correctly, see this [question (django-override-admin-template)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14754545/django-override-admin-template) for more clarifications.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can move your code into 
    {% block nav-global %}{% endblock %}
Example, in your template file, something like this:

```
{% block nav-global %}
    {% for app in app_list %}
        <li>
            <a href="#">
                <img src="{{ MEDIA_URL }}images/list.png"/>
                <span>{{ app.name }}</span>
            </a>
            <ul class="drawer" style="display: none;">
                {% for model in app.models %}
                    <li>
                        <a href="{{ model.admin_url }}">
                           <span>{{ model.name }}</span>
                        </a>
                   </li>
                {% endfor %}
           </ul>
       </li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
......
{% endblock %}
```